# question on the working of instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

```
Long l1 = null;
Long l2 = Long.getLong("23");
Long l3 = Long.valueOf(23);

System.out.println(l1 instanceof Long);  // returns false
System.out.println(l2 instanceof Long);  // returns false
System.out.println(l3 instanceof Long);  // returns true
```

I could not understand the output returned. I was expecting true atleast for 2nd and 3rd syso's. Can someone explain how instanceof works?

Comment: why you require the complete code for this?

Comment: you should do `System.out.println(l1);...` etc. this would show you what is happening.

Comment: For l2, perhaps you should use Long.parseLong(String)
See <http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29>

Answer (score 17):

This has nothing to do with `instanceof`. The method `Long.getLong()` does not parse the string, it returns the contents of a system property with that name, interpreted as long. Since there is no system property with the name 23, it returns null. You want `Long.parseLong()`

Answer (score 11):

> `l1 instanceof Long`

since `l1` is **null**, **instanceof** yields **false** (as specified by the Java languange specs)

> `l2 instanceof Long`

this yields **false** since you are using the wrong method `getLong`:

`Determines the long value of the system property with the specified name.`

Comment: see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 7):

`Long.getLong(..)` returns the long value of a system property. It returns `null` in your case, because there is no system property named "23". So:

- 1 and 2 are `null`, and `instanceof` returns `false` when comparing nulls
- 3 is `java.lang.Long` (you can check by outputting `l3.getClass()`) so `true` is expected

Instead of using `Long.getLong(..)`, use `Long.parseLong(..)` to parse a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one can rewrite the sop's as :

```
System.out.println(l1 != null && l1 instanceof Long);
System.out.println(l2 != null && l2 instanceof Long);
System.out.println(l3 != null && l3 instanceof Long);
```

As always `null` cannot be an `instanceof` anything.

Answer (score 0):

the instance of will check the type of the object under inspection.

In you the first two will have null value for which it returns false. and the 3rd one has the Long object which return true.

You can get more info on instaceof at this java glossary site: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instanceof.html

Answer (score 0):

Long l1 = null;  // false by default null is false for instanceof

Long l2 = Long.getLong("23");   //true if "23" is present in systeme property with long value otherwise false

Long l3 = Long.valueOf(23); // true because 23 is instanceof Long